# Improving the user experiense of a slow Flask view

Tags: python, flask, server-response

I have an anchor tag that hits a route which generates a report in a new tab. I am lazyloading the report specs because I don't want to have copies of my data in the original place and on the report object. But collecting that data takes 10-20 seconds.

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/report/')
@app.route('/report/<id>')
def report(id=None):
    report_specs = function_that_takes_20_seconds(id)
    return render_template('report.html', report_specs=report_specs)
```

I'm wondering what I can do so that the server responds immediately with a spinner and then when function_that_takes_20_seconds is done, load the report.

Comment: Jobs running longer than a few seconds are good work for a task queue like celery.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: a HTTP view is not a place for a long running tasks.

You need think your system architecture: what you can prepare outside the view and what computations must happen real time in a view.

The usual solutions include adding asynchronous properties and processing your data in a separate process. Often people use schedulers like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this.

- Prepare data in a scheduled process which runs for e.g. every 10 minutes
- Cache results by storing them in a database
- HTTP view always returns the last cached version

This, or then make a your view to do an [AJAX call via JavaScript](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/) ("the spinner approach"). This requires obtaining some basic JavaScript skills. However this doesn't make the results appear to an end user any faster - it's just user experience smoke and mirrors.